# Force git to show merge conflicts

Tags: git, merge

We did something stupid, when we realised builds were failing instead of a rollback we manually fixed the error.

So basically,

- We were working on a branch A with library v1, we merged the branch into master. Later we realised the builds were failing and instead of a rollback we switched to library v2 everywhere manually.
- Soon other code was also merged into master including in files where earlier library v1 was used and now library v2 was being used.
- Now later on we realised a fix for library v1 was available so we went on branch A and made some commits and it started working.

When I try to merge master onto branch A, all the changes in the files where we shifted v1 to v2 are automatically overwritten on branch A. Which makes sense because these changes were made on master after the branches forked and now git is bringing these changes to the branch A.

Is there a way I can trigger a merge conflict on specific files, i.e. Make some files in branch A register as new changes which triggers a merge conflict with master. This way I can easily choose which changes to pick from branch A and which ones from master.

Also suggestions how we could have handled things better, other than a rollback.